# SSIS - Execute task works quickly but execute package works as lifelong

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I installed the most recent version of visual studio and SSDT (so all settings are default) and I created a simple package which works completely fine in less than two seconds when I execute it by right click and then press "execute task".

However when I right-click on package and then press "execute package" it takes more than three minutes and in progress no error.

How can I resolve this problem?
i also cannot connect my SSIS when i open it "Run As Administrator". Both SSMS and SQL Server are 17 and on the same machine.

Comment: Are you literally out of memory on your local machine? Try closing some programs (browsers...).

Comment: No, memory is fine and in my package there is only a single task which could be run in less than a second

Comment: Which version of visual studio did you install?

Comment: 15.9.6 which the latest version

Comment: Have you seen this post - https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/692952/SSIS-Warning--Global-Shared-Memory ?

Comment: One other question, is the account you are running the visual studio under, is that account an administrator on that machine?  Or can you run visual studio as Administrator?

Comment: Yes i saw that link too, yes both SSDT and sql server and everything else are running at the same mashine as administrator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187867/discussion-between-bobf-and-anfi).

Answer (score 1):

SSIS usually takes a bit longer than 1 sec to run a package as it has to do a full validation phase first.

Also -You might have multiple tasks in your package (not necessarily connected)...
When you "execute package" - all tasks are ran but when you "execute task" then only the selected task is being ran.

I would not worry too much about this warning message.
It is not strictly related to your issue as I have seen it lots of times and usually just filter it out as it only appears via VS.
You can demonstrate this by opening up a cmd shell and running the package via DTEXEC.exe.
EG:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional>dtexec.exe
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 12.0.4100.1 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

pass in your saved ssis package and you will see the output of the package execution.

Comment: Thank you, but I simply create a SINGLE task, it takes almost a second but when I execute package it takes longer than 3 mintunes. Let’s say in this way, forget about the warning, my SSDT setting is default and a single simple task execution via package takes too long.